# How to add class in element on scroll React js

Tags: reactjs

How to add class in element on scroll React js, I want to add class in  on scroll and remove that class if on top of the page.

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "react-router"
import { prefixLink } from "gatsby-helpers"
import Helmet from "react-helmet"
import { config } from "config"

module.exports = React.createClass({
  propTypes() {
    return {
      children: React.PropTypes.any,
    }
  },
  render() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => {

    });
    return (
      <div>
        <header className="header">
          <div className="top-bar">
            <span><a href="tel:6788272782">678-827-2782 </a></span>
            <span><a href="mailto:hellohello@knotel.com"> hellohello@knotel.com</a></span>
            <button>Login</button>
          </div>
        </header>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  },

})
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use state to manage classnames and update state in the scroll event. Also, you should move the scroll event binding into the componentDidMount function instead of render.

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "react-router"
import { prefixLink } from "gatsby-helpers"
import Helmet from "react-helmet"
import { config } from "config"

module.exports = React.createClass({
  propTypes() {
    return {
      children: React.PropTypes.any,
    }
  },
  componentDidMount(){
      window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
         let activeClass = 'normal';
         if(window.scrollY === 0){
             activeClass = 'top';
         }
         this.setState({ activeClass });
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <header className="header">
          <div className={`top-bar ${this.state.activeClass}`}>
            <span><a href="tel:6788272782">678-827-2782 </a></span>
            <span><a href="mailto:hellohello@knotel.com"> hellohello@knotel.com</a></span>
            <button>Login</button>
          </div>
        </header>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  },

})
```

Comment: @harry dont forget to removeEventListener in componentWillUnmount too!

componentWillUnmount() {
   window.removeEventListener('scroll');
}

Answer (score 32):

**If you want to use React Hooks in 2020 stateless component**

```
const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(false);
 useEffect(() => {
   window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
     setScroll(window.scrollY > 50);
   });
 }, []);
```

and use it anywhere in your code

```
className={scroll ? "bg-black" : "bg-white"}
```

setScroll(window.scrollY > 50); here 50 specify the height.

Comment: not working :-(

Answer (score 2):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { Link } from "react-router"
import { prefixLink } from "gatsby-helpers"
import Helmet from "react-helmet"
import { config } from "config"

export default function Header(props) {
  const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      setScroll(window.scrollY > 10)
    })
  }, [])
  return (
    <header className={scroll ? "main-header scrolled" : "main-header"}>
</header>
  )
}
```

Comment: This is best implementation. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 1):

One more variant with hooks and cleanup to avoid memory leaks, if the browser is not handled it properly.

```
const [isScrollValueMoreThanHeaderHeight, setIsScrollValueMoreThanHeaderHeight] = useState(false);

//here 96(px) - height of current header

useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
        setIsScrollValueMoreThanHeaderHeight(window.scrollY > 96);
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
},[])
```

And then used it in a ternary way to change class

```
className={isScrollValueMoreThanHeaderHeight ? "class1" : "class2"}
```